# How to move property setting in Struct initialization into another method

Tags: swift, struct, initialization

So I have a struct, call `DemoType`, where I want the caller to initialize it with two properties-- however I also want to expose the ability to set the second property,

the problem is that before setting `prop2`, there is quite a lot of logic that needs to run first.  **This means that there is a lot of repeat lines of code**, which I'm trying to reduce by keeping that logic in one place.  I would like to keep it all in `setProp2`

```
struct DemoType {
    var prop1: String
    var prop2: String

    init?(p1:String, p2:String) {
        self.prop1 = p1
        let potentialFailure = true
        guard potentialFailure else { return nil }
        // Like 20 lines of logic here manipulating p2
        self.prop2 = p2
    }

    mutating func setProp2(_ p2:String) {
        let potentialFailure = true
        guard potentialFailure else { return }
        // Like 20 lines of logic here manipulating p2
        self.prop2 = p2
    }

}
```

So from a logical standpoint, I could just call `setProp`, and everything would be cool

```
struct DemoType {
    var prop1: String
    var prop2: String

    init?(p1:String, p2:String) {
        self.prop1 = p1
        self.setProp2(p2)
    }

    mutating func setProp2(_ p2:String) {
        let potentialFailure = true
        guard potentialFailure else { return }
        // Like 20 lines of logic here manipulating p2
        self.prop2 = p2
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler will complain that I have not initialized all of my properties in the `init`,

**and** also i want the init to be `fallable`, so it can return `nil` if certain checks fail, so I'm not sure how I would do that with this implementation, as I can make `setProp2` just return, but then how do I make the caller (`init`) return `nil`?

I imagine what I'm trying to do must be possible, but I just don't know the syntax the compiler is looking for.  Alternatively I could pull those 20 lines of logic out into it's own method and have both call it, that would be cleaner as well, but because both call `self.prop2` at the end, I was hoping there would be a way to just have one place where `self.prop2` is assigned

Comment: This is a fair indication that this "20 lines of logic" should not be hidden away in an initializer or setter. Make a separate function that describes exactly what that logic is, and call that from both the setter and the initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be because your mutating set function can return early before setting the property. I suggest creating a function that configures prop2 and returns either the successfully configured prop, or a `nil` for an unsuccessful configuration:

```
func setProp2(_ prop2: String) -> Prop2? {
  // set up 
  return prop2
}
```

Now you can call `setProp2` both from the initializer and from the mutating set function. This alleviates the duplicated code problem.

Comment: yesss that's perfect, thanks!  Looks much better now